# I have imported a project into Xcode. It is giving an error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have imported a project into Xcode. It is giving an error that is unexpected identifier (.

File name is `SignIn.h`

and code that is written in this file is

```
../../../../Google/Headers/SignIn.h
```

Comment: check if files are present in the directory..

Comment: Which code file has this particular error? The `unexpected identifier` message is emitted by the parser, and normally indicates a syntax error.

Comment: yes, it is a parse issue with import <Google/SignIn.h> in MyLoginViewController.m. How to resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

Add this line in your bridging Header file and import `Google` in AppDelegate

```
import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>

import <Google/Core.h>
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: It's not working, while I have added these lines then it' showing "missing context for method declaration" for every method declaration and expected method body as well.